# Blender 2.8 - How to render shadows to separate file outputs

Tags: rendering, shadows

I'm doing a simple product mockup with an object sitting on a plane. when rendering What i really would like is two files to move into photoshop for editing...

One file with the product on a completely transparent background. With light+shadows still affecting the object. Then another file with just the background shadows on a transparent background, separate from the object.

or simply put, just a deep etched image without having to do it manually in photoshop.

I'm currently using shadow catcher and have a transparent background set, but i can't render the two separately without somehow affecting the other. I'm new to blender and this workflow and it's proving to be quite frustrating. any help would be appreciated!